How do I properly call a function that excecute queries against a MySQL Server from many threads?
I have a WinForm App that create one thread for each TCP incoming connection; each thread parse the data, perform many queries using a MySQL connector dll. The code of the threads is getting a bit long, so I'm trying to create external functions to get a more clean code, but I don't fully understand how the underlying code manages this. I have the sensation that something can end really bad doing it by this way.
    Private Function GetCmd(Byval VehiID as String, Byval Account as String) as string 'Get first Command not sent
    {
        'Ask to MySQL server
         Using conn As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.CnnSQL)
         conn.Open()
             Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
             cmd.Connection = conn
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
         

            End Using
        End Using
    }
    
    Private Sub StartTcpClient(ByVal client As TcpClient)'There's around 100 of this threads running
    {
         Dim CmdX as String = GetCmd("AAA123","123456")
    
    }


Well, this code does not do anything.

@Shadow I know. Is just a sketch to give an idea on how the function is being called from the thread. Inside the StartTcpClient there's many calls to functions that parser all the data and some things are done inside the thread itself. I just want to know if is safe to call functions that performs querys to the database from many threads.

Mysql can handle multiple comcurrent connections.

@Shadow I know, but I don't understand, for example, if GetCmd can be called at same time by different threads without creating any issue.

It depends what other things getcmd will do. It is pretty difficult to help, if your question is so generic!

@Shadow Nothing more. It just retrieve data from the database.
